# Browser is not getting the last version of javascript file

Tags: javascript, azure-devops

I'm having a problem with browser cache of javascript files.
During my publication, the hash of the modified files is changed correctly, and I can see this change by listing the files inside the server, as in the image below:

[image]

The featured file is new because have thew last changed in a specific screen. When i open my browse and open this new screen, the browser shows the old version of the file:

[image]

If I open the same screen in a "incognito tab", the new version is showed. How to guarantee that the user will always access the latest version without having to "force" a browser update?

Comment: What JS file is *directly* referenced by the main HTML page? Does it have a hashed filename or not?

Comment: @spender, is the file "main". and it have a hashed filename too. The only file that doesn't have hash is index.html

Answer (score 0):

So, your main HTML page is being cached more aggressively than you would like.

You need to change the HTTP headers served with your resources.

For unhashed resources (i.e. files with no hash in their file-name), I would suggest using something like:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

or perhaps

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=900
```

which would give a 15m expiry time. Having an expiry-time that exceeds the time taken to deploy a new build can be desirable.

For hashed files, I would suggest something super-aggressive, such as

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000, immutable
```

to hold them in cache for 1 year.

**Some helpful links:**

[MDN docs on Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control#immutable)

[React docs about production deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/#static-file-caching) (concepts are good, even if you're not using React)